# Dynamically change docstring of instance method

Tags: python, docstring, instance-methods

Here is a minimum example of a class that holds a function as an attribute and has a method that is calling said function.

```
class MyClass:

    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f

    def func(self):
        """This is the docstring to be replaced."""
        return self.f()
```

The function `f` can change during runtime and I would like to dynamically change the docstring of `func` to reflect the current function stored in `f`.

I was thinking of achieving this by using properties and setter to change the docstring of `func` as soon as a new `f` is assigned.

```
class MyClass:

    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f
    
    @property
    def f(self):
        return self._f

    @f.setter
    def f(self, value):
        self._f = value
        self.func.__doc__ = value.__doc__

    def func(self):
        """This is the docstring to be replaced"""
        return self.f()
```

The usage would be as follows

```
def func():
    """This is the docstring to be shown"""
    return True

obj = MyClass(func)
```

with the goal that calling `help(obj.func)` would display `"This is the docstring to be shown"`.

However, it seems like docstrings of instance methods are not replaceable.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[3], line 1
----> 1 obj = MyClass(func)

Cell In[1], line 4, in MyClass.__init__(self, f)
      3 def __init__(self, f):
----> 4     self.f = f

Cell In[1], line 13, in MyClass.f(self, value)
     10 @f.setter
     11 def f(self, value):
     12     self._f = value
---> 13     self.func.__doc__ = value.__doc__

AttributeError: attribute '__doc__' of 'method' objects is not writable
```

Is there any way of achieving this?

Comment: A note to point out here, is that the docstrings are associated with the base class definition, not the instance of the class. A better idea here would be to surface the documentation (i.e. the state of the instance) by providing a `__repr__` method that can be examined using the `repr` builtin function.

Answer (score 1):

You need to distinguish between the `function`-valued class attribute that has a docstring and the `method` object created on demand for the evaluation of the expression `self.func`. `self.func` and `MyClass.func` are *not* the same object.

You'll need to use `type(self)` or more explicitly `MyClass.func` in order to change the docstring of the correct object.

```
class MyClass:

    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f
    
    @property
    def f(self):
        return self._f

    @f.setter
    def f(self, value):
        self._f = value
        type(self).func.__doc__ = value.__doc__

    def func(self):
        """This is the docstring to be replaced"""
        return self.f()
```

Keep in mind, though, that this is not a way to create instance-specific doc strings. `MyClass.func` is a single object shared by all instances. The problem before is that given instances `a` and `b` of `MyClass`, not only are `a.func` and `b.func` different `method` objects derived *from* that function, but even `x = a.func` and `y = a.func` are separate instances of `method` derived from the same function.

Comment: I would be careful of any class instance updating the class itself. If you have multiple instances of the class, they'll clobber eachothers work.